# exact mechanics of istream::operator>> to string

Tags: c++, istream

I'm just not seeing this:

```
std::istringstream stream(somestring);

string temp;
stream >> temp;
```

In the last line, what is the exact function called? I can't find it in the list on [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/). Thanks!

Comment: `std::istringstream` and `string`? Where's `std::` in the latter?

Comment: You mean a `std::` or a `.c_str()`? The latter is not required in c++0x.

Comment: Ah, you should have mentioned so. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If memory serves, it's a non-member function overload -- have a signature something like:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, std::string &s);
```

(For the moment I've left out the fact that both `istream` and `string` are really typedefs of template instantiations).

Comment: Dang, just found it here: http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/operator%3E%3E/ Guess it's not listed because it's just not declared in the `<istream>` header... Thanks though, you weirdly pointed me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean `istream& operator>> (istream& is, string& str);`?

(on [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/operator%3E%3E/))